# Alert a element after change in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want alert a message after change or click on option in select box, but don't work for me.

What do i do?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/byw5H/

My code:

```
//Html Code
<select name="mainpage" size="6">
  <option value="1">11111111</option>
  <option value="2">22222222</option>
  <option value="3">33333333</option>
  <option value="4">44444444</option>
  <option value="5">55555555</option>
  <option value="6">66666666</option>
</select>​

//Js Code
$('select[name="mainpage"]').live('change',function(){
    alert('ok');
)}​
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code: the `)}` token at the end should be `});`.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated use `.on()` instead. And as stated you are missing `;` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the JavaScript console

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

)}
```

That points to

```
$('select[name="mainpage"]').live('change',function(){
    alert('ok');
)}​  <-- HERE
```

You switched them! Correct order is `})`

```
$('select[name="mainpage"]').live('change',function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax error -

```
$('select[name="mainpage"]').live('change',function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

As others said, its a syntax error.

Apart from that, you can do this in other way too:-

```
$('select[name="mainpage"]').change(function(){
    alert('ok');
});​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/byw5H/6/)**